# Adding objects into array

Tags: javascript, canvas

Could someone tell me what's wrong with this code ? I am trying to fill canvas with squares as objects but as the loop is done and i am trying to draw that square on canvas nothing happens...

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(35, 180, 218)";

var rectHeight = 5;
var rectWidth = 5;

var cells = [];

for (var i = 0; i <= canvas.width/rectWidth; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x <= canvas.height/rectHeight; x++) {
        cells[i] = {
            posX : i*rectWidth,
            posY : x*rectHeight,
            draw : function() {
                ctx.fillRect(posX, posY, rectWidth, rectHeight);
            },
            clear : function() {
                ctx.clearRect(posX, posY, rectWidth, rectHeight);
            }
        };
    }
}

cells[2].draw;
```

Comment: You’re overwriting `cells[i]` `canvas.height / rectHeight - 1` times.

Comment: draw is a function and should be called like `cells[2].draw()`

Comment: @SimranjitSingh Which will then throw a `ReferenceError`

Comment: @Andreas Right. It should be `this.posX` and `this.posY` in the arguments.

Comment: You are rught @Andreas it should use this.position or calculate position before object creation. See the snippet below, it adds a rectangle( somehow ) but at the bottom right corner. It is not rendering 5x5 square though.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, i have already fixed the problem.. Main problem was as @Xufox said that i was overwriting cells in the array... Other bugs i have made while i was trying to fix it with mad overwrites.. Thanks again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help @Xufox @SimranjitSingh and @Andreas..

Code now works like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(35, 180, 218)";

var rectHeight = 5;
var rectWidth = 5;

var cells = [];

for (var i = 0; i <= canvas.width/rectWidth; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x <= canvas.height/rectHeight; x++) {
        cells[i*x] = {
            posX : i*rectWidth,
            posY : x*rectHeight,
            draw : function() {
                ctx.fillRect(this.posX, this.posY, rectWidth, rectHeight);
            },
            clear : function() {
                ctx.clearRect(this.posX, this.posY, rectWidth, rectHeight);
            }
        };
    }
}

cells[2].draw();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";

var rectHeight = 15;
var rectWidth = 15;

var cells = [];

for (var i = 0; i <= canvas.width/rectWidth; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x <= canvas.height/rectHeight; x++) {
        cells[i] = {
            posX : i*rectWidth,
            posY : x*rectHeight,
            draw : function() {
                ctx.fillRect(this.posX, this.posY, rectWidth, rectHeight);
            },
            clear : function() {
                ctx.clearRect(positionX, positionY, rectWidth, rectHeight);
            }
        };
    }
}
cells[2].draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Global variables are almost always _not_ the solution

Comment: using this.position variables.